# "How is it built?"

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, stackexchange

Where do I ask a "how is it built?" question about an application.

Assume I find a webpage or an app, and would like to learn more around what languages and frameworks that are used. I think I would find the answers a good entry point for understanding technologies and for inspiration, trying to learn to build something that is new to me. But at the same time, this type of question is not necessarily answerable.

Is Programmers.SE, or are any other SE site, suited for these kinds of questions?

Comment: "How is it built" is probably not going to work anywhere on Stack Exchange (chat being the obvious exception). "How did this project solve this specific problem" _might_ work on Programmers, assuming of course we are talking about a design problem.

Comment: I've seen questions like this work on Programmers and SO before, however its important to approach the question as *"I would like to do X and am not sure how to go about it. ABC over here has an example of the exact behavior I want, but I don't know how they accomplish it"*. This way, you're presenting an actual problem you're facing to be solved, and only using the other company as an example, instead of asking directly how the other company does something. The first we can help you with. The 2nd, not so much because you'd need an expert in that company's system to get an authoritative answer

Comment: Your best bet for "how is it built" might be to find an open-source project and look over the code yourself.

Comment: Good answers. It would be fun though, to find a forum where programmers try to "see through" applications. I see now that it would not be in SE's Q&A format. Here's something like that: http://builtwith.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really wouldn't work on any SE site, however for discussion topics like this you are more than welcome to join [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) and bring up any topic you like, there's fairly consistent activity in there throughout the day with experts from the industry.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few "how do I learn from existing open source architectures" scattered around here. The answers usually point to [Architecture of Open Source Applications](http://www.aosabook.org/en/index.html) which is a great resource!